# Corner radius for inner views, React Native

Tags: react-native

I applied style with cornerRadius for a container view, it has next settings:

```
container: {
    height: 100,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#51C979',
    marginLeft: 8,
    marginRight: 8,
    marginBottom: 4,
    marginTop: 4,
    borderRadius: 10
},
```

I divide this container into two subviews with styles:

```
leftContainer: {
    flex: 1
},
rightContainer: {
    flex: 1
},
```

Hierarchy looks like this:

```
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
                <Text style={[styles.nameText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.activity.name} </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                <Text style={[styles.durationText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.activity.duration + ' hrs'} </Text>
                <Text style={[styles.rangeText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.activity.timeRangeStringRepresentation} </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
```

After this, only bottom corners have radius. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the Text component has background color on iOS

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
            <Text style={[styles.nameText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.activity.name} </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
            <Text style={[styles.durationText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.activity.duration + ' hrs'} </Text>
            <Text style={[styles.rangeText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.activity.timeRangeStringRepresentation} </Text>
        </View>
    </View>
```

to fix that add background color transparent to the Text component

```
textColor:{
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
}
```